# Microk8s kubectl alias

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to microk8s, it's a wonderful and easy approach to setup k8s, just one thing which is quite annoying which is to use **microk8s** everytime before the **kubectl** command, is there any way to use kubectl directly or make it a alias.

For eg to run kubectl command, I've to use microk8s everytime ==> microk8s kubectl get pods

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, there is a way to create an alias for kubectl in microk8s,
run this command

`sudo snap alias microk8s.kubectl kubectl`

and you will be able to use kubectl directly.